# Spring implementation of Guavas Futures.transform

Tags: java, spring, guava

I know that spring has its own implementation of `ListenableFuture`, but does it have a similar implementation of `Futures.transform`? I'm trying to find a way to chain operations together using the classes spring provides, but I only see examples using Guava.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Springs implementation appears to be `ListenableFutureAdapter`

Here is an example:

```
@Service
public class HeavyLiftingServiceImpl implements IHeavyLiftingService {

    public ListenableFuture<String> heavyLifting() {
        AsyncRestTemplate asycTemp = new AsyncRestTemplate();
        ListenableFuture<String> future = asycTemp.execute(url, method, requestCallback, responseExtractor, urlVariable);

        ListenableFutureAdapter<String, String> chainedFuture;
        chainedFuture = new ListenableFutureAdapter<String, String>(future) {

            @Override
            protected String adapt(String adapteeResult)
                    throws ExecutionException {
                        String parsedString = parse(adapteeResult);
                        return adapteeResult;
            }
        };

        return chainedFuture;
    }

}
```

I would recommend using Guava's implementation of listenable future. It is more readable and there is a lot more documentation on chaining them together